# Converting to mathematic?

Tags: javascript

How can i convert my mathematic piece, so it doesnt just return the number and the operator

I tried with:

```
<script>
    function visResultat() {
        var tal1 = document.getElementById("txtTal1").value;
        var tal2 = document.getElementById("txtTal2").value;
        var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
        var resultatet = parseInt(tal1) + operator + parseInt(tal2);
        resultat.innerHTML = resultatet;
    }
</script>
```

right now it just returns the number in textbox 1 & 2 and the operator selected from the select menu. EXAMPLE on how it is right now:

42+23

EXAMPLE on how i want it to look like.

65

i'm totally new the javascript - Thanks, Anton

Comment: you probably have to run eval on it, or have a list of operators and functions that operate on the numbers for a given operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to realistically do that (which is unsafe), is by using an `eval()` statement. `operator` is just a string, it can't act like a math operator without `eval`.

```
var resultatet = eval(parseInt(tal1) + operator + parseInt(tal2));
```

The safe but tedious method would be to simply use if statements or a switch to perform the proper math operation on the inputs.

```
if (operator === "+") //do addition
if (operator === "*") //multiply
//etc
```

PS: always a good idea to use a radix on the `parseInt` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use a hashmap to determine how to "operate" on the inputs

  function visResultat() {
    var operatorList = {
      "+":function(a,b){return a+b},
      "-":function(a,b){return a-b},
      "*":function(a,b){return a*b},
      "/":function(a,b){return a/b}
    }
    var tal1 = document.getElementById("txtTal1").value;
    var tal2 = document.getElementById("txtTal2").value;
    var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    var resultatet = operatorList[operator](tal1,tal2);
    resultat.innerHTML = resultatet;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator you're trying to use is a string, so JavaScript will just "merge" your variables assuming all next to it are strings. Since you're starting I'd hardly recommend you creating some a decision statement like if or switch. Something like:

```
function visResultat() {
    var tal1 = document.getElementById("txtTal1").value;
    var tal2 = document.getElementById("txtTal2").value;
    var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;

    if (operator == '+') {
        resultatet = parseInt(tal1) + parseInt(tal2);
    }
    else if( operator == '-'){
        resultatet = parseInt(tal1) - parseInt(tal2);
    }
    else if(operator == '*'){
        resultatet = parseInt(tal1) * parseInt(tal2);
    }
    else if(operator == '/'){
        resultatet = parseInt(tal1) / parseInt(tal2);
    }
    resultat.innerHTML = resultatet;
}
```

There are a lot of better ways to do this, but this is probably the easiest to understand at first sight.